Wheel collider making my car jump in Unity
I’m making a racing game in Unity and every time the car touches the ground, it just jumps. I’ve seen people complaining about it multiple times, but usually adding mass of about 2000 to the car or making damper on wheel collider lower helps, but for me it doesn’t. I have another box collider, and some people said that helped them. I also don’t have isTrigger on on any of my colliders. But it’s worth noting that I’m using Road Architect made by FritzsHero, so I don’t know if there’s a problem because of that. I’m using Unity 2022.3.50f1 to be specific.
